# How to Display 10 number per line. Each number occupies 6 places.

Tags: java

I am asked to write a java program using methods that display the 1st 100 Palindromic prime numbers. I need to Display 10 number per line. Each number occupies 6 places. I did the whole program but I'm stuck with how can each number occupy 6 places I don't know to do it. So how can I make each number occupy 6 places?

```
public class PalindromicPrime {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int NUMBER_OF_PALINPRIME = 100;
    int numberPrinted = 0, testedNumber = 2;

 while (numberPrinted < NUMBER_OF_PALINPRIME) {
    if (isPrime(testedNumber) && isPalindrome(testedNumber)) {
        numberPrinted++;
        System.out.print(testedNumber + " ");
    if (numberPrinted % 10 == 0) {
        System.out.println();
}//end of 2nd if
} //end of 1st if
testedNumber++;



}// end while




} // main method




/** Check whether number is prime */
 public static boolean isPrime(int number) {
    for (int divisor = 2; divisor <= number / 2; divisor++) {
    if (number % divisor == 0) { // If true, number is not prime
    return false; // number is not a prime
   } // end if
  } // end for loop



    return true; // number is prime
 } // end isPrime method
public static int reverse(int number) {


int reverse = 0;
  int digit;

  do {
   digit = number % 10;
   reverse = reverse * 10 + digit;
   number /= 10;
  } // end do;
  while (number != 0);

  return reverse;
 } // end reverse method

 public static boolean isPalindrome(int number) {

  return (number == reverse(number));

 } // end isPalindrome method

} // end class
```

Comment: Look into printing formatted text. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `String.format`to align the text and then use `print`  as shown below :

```
while (numberPrinted < NUMBER_OF_PALINPRIME) {
     if (isPrime(testedNumber) && isPalindrome(testedNumber)) {
     numberPrinted++;
     System.out.print(String.format("%6s ", testedNumber));//formats to 6 positions

      if (numberPrinted % 10 == 0) {
           System.out.println();
      }
   } 
   testedNumber++;
}
```

Also, as a side note, ensure that your code is indentated properly so that it will be more readable so that it does not require unnecessary comments like 1st `if`, 2nd `if`, etc.